# Seleccion de un Jtable - Java

Tags: java

Cuando selecciono una fila, se selecciona todo pero la celda que selecciono en el borde aparecen unos puntitos, como puediera quitarlos o modificarlos.
La propiedad del JTable que utilizo para seleccionar toda la fila es : `rowSelectionAllowed`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes hacerte un render específico que no te ponga un borde en la celda seleccionada:

```
//En tu caso es la columna nº 1
getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {

  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
     boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
     Component c = table.getDefaultRenderer(table.getColumnClass(column))
        .getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

     //Si la celda está seleccionada quitamos el borde
     if(isSelected)
        ((JComponent)c).setBorder(null);

     return c;
  }
});
```